# Run auto_close when there are several workbooks open

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run VBA code whenever a workbook closes

I tried both `Private Sub auto_close()` inside the Module and `Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)` inside "ThisWorkbook". They both work when there is a single file open but not if there are multiple files open.

The problem is that it seems that if there are several Excel files (workbooks) open at the same time, this seems to not work. Only if I close them to the point when there is only a single file open, then the code is executed

Comment: The scope of both of your solutions is the current workbook. If you are trying to close and or  all the open workbooks you'd need a Public scope and place it in your Personal.xlsm or Personal .xlsb workbook and either have it operate on ActiveWorkbook or iterate through all the open workbooks. HTH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Prevent Closing Workbooks Using a Class

- Note that this code goes into three different modules. I'm a newb when it comes to classes, I've only once built something similar. I don't understand when or why it stops (but sometimes it does). So if you run into trouble, ask another question (you have a class related code now) and put `Class` in the title and hopefully someone more qualified could answer.
- The only possibly new thing for you is the third code, which has to go into a class module. Insert a new class module (`Class1`) and in the properties window change `Class1` to `wbCloser`. Copy the codes into the appropriate modules and save the workbook. Then run `AppEventsInit` in the standard module.
- Note that every time you open this workbook, `AppEventsInit` will run (`Workbooks_Open`).

**`ThisWorkbook`**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    AppEventsInit
End Sub
```

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```
Option Explicit

Public AppEvent As New wbCloser ' Class Name ('wbCloser')

Sub AppEventsInit()
    Set AppEvent.App = Application
End Sub
```

**Class Module: `Class1` renamed to `wbCloser`**

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub App_WorkbookBeforeClose(ByVal Wb As Workbook, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim msg As Variant
    msg = MsgBox("The workbook '" & Wb.Name _
        & "' is trying to close. Will you allow it?", vbYesNo)
    If msg = vbYes Then
        'Cancel = False ' by default
        MsgBox "You allowed closing of '" & Wb.Name & "'."
    Else
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox "You prevented closing of '" & Wb.Name & "'."
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    ' Remove if it doesn't work.
    Application.Speech.Speak "Workbook Clozer Initialized"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
After opening the VBA and inserting a module type in this:

Sub CloseAllActiveWorkbooks()

Workbooks.close

End sub